# Does using frameworks take up more memory then directly including the source in your app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I've written some general use code that was originally part of a single app. Realizing that I could use the code in my new project made me move the source to their own frameworks where I can use carthage to manage it.

How does creating a framework for each of these affect the apps size? Also, just to note, some of the source's are only a single file wrapped up as a framework.

Comment: In the title, you ask about memory usage, in the body about app size (disk space). Which one is it?

Comment: Hi, sorry about the ambiguity. I originally intended to ask about disk space but, actually, both would be nice to know.